# Making outdented/grayed block in CV

Tags: resume

[This page](http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/5) has a tutorial for making CV, but it doesn't have the example to make grayed/outdented section as follows:

[image]

How can I make this?
The copied code from the poster without the outdenting/grayed area is as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\rmfamily\scshape}

% add the symbols for email and phone contact data
\cofoot{\so{Liefdestraat, 7 - 1234LI, Amsterdam, Nederland}\\
\so{ {\Large\Letter} jeff@gmail.com \ {\Large\Telefon} +31 (0)6 12345678}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\textsc{\Huge{\so{Iulius Caesar}}}

\section{Experiences}
\section{Skills}
\section{Education}
\section{Publications}
\section{Personal Info}
\section{Languages}
\section{Interests}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

#### Update package if necessary

One needs to update enumitem package with `tlmgr update --self` when the output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: You can use the package `framed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following could be a start:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{framed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/framed
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\newlist{experience}{description}{1}
\setlist[experience]{labelwidth=7em,align=right}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.9}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\rmfamily\scshape}

% add the symbols for email and phone contact data
\cofoot{\so{Liefdestraat, 7 - 1234LI, Amsterdam, Nederland}\\
\so{ {\Large\Letter} jeff@gmail.com \ {\Large\Telefon} +31 (0)6 12345678}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \textsc{\Huge{\so{Iulius Caesar}}}
\end{center}

\section{Experiences}
\begin{shaded}
  \begin{experience}
    \item[Period] \textbf{October 2006 --- today}
    \item[Employer] \textbf{TomTom BV} \hfill Amsterdam, The Netherlands\mbox{\hspace*{.5em}}
    \item[Job Title] \textbf{Architect/Senior Programmer}
    \item[Languages] C++, Java
  \end{experience}
\end{shaded}
\begin{experience}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\FrameRule+7em+\labelsep]
  \item[] \unskip\lipsum[1]
\end{experience}

\section{Skills}
\section{Education}
\section{Publications}
\section{Personal Info}
\section{Languages}
\section{Interests}

\end{document}
```

Items are organised within an `experience` list which is based on `description`. All of which are set using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) provides the shaded box (via the `shaded` environment), while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides some dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum*-style.

Settings for the `shaded` box is controlled via `\FrameRule` and `\FrameSep`, while the color is set using `\definecolor{shadecolor}`. Read more on this in the [`framed` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/framed/framed.pdf).

Comment: I tried your solution to get a different result, and I updated my post. Could you care to check?

Comment: @prosseek: Did you compile my MWE as-is? If so, please include `\listfiles` in your preamble and include the contents *after* `*File List*` in your `.log` file. It could be that you have an outdated [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) (my version is 2011/09/28 v3.5.2).

Comment: Yes, it works fine with the package update. Thanks.